# ssh - Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, xforwarding

I am trying to run an indirect GLX program through X11 forwarded ssh.  Where the graphics are rendered on the X server side.  The ssh server is running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (will refer to as ubuntu), and ssh client Arch Linux (will refer to as arch).

I start the Xserver on arch with `xinit xfce4-session -- +iglx`, and connect to ubuntu with `ssh connor@server -Xp 23`, I then run `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` then proceed to start glx clients.  Below I tried running some glx programs:

```
connor@server:~$ glxinfo
name of display: localhost:10.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
connor@server:~$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

These are the graphics devices for arch:

```
[connor@archlinux ~]$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)
```

In the SSH session the graphical devices are as follows:

```
connor@server:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

Ubuntu seems to be suggessful on X connections, such as running xterm or xeyes, its sshd config contains:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

I have tried to run the X server with `-listen tcp` also allowiing remore with `xhost +`.  On ubuntu, instead set `DISPLAY=arch:0.0`.  But still no success with the exact same results.  Strangely, connecting through the windows port of Xorg; VcXsrv, I am able to connect with putty with what I assume to be indirect rendering, as frame-rates are reaching levels of 60fps on full 1920p display on the same hardware and connection (comparable to my previous results of 5fps at low-res).

I ask for potential solutions and help, my frustration has developed over a week after trying everything I can think of with the same results.  My last resort is installing Arch linux on the Ubuntu server, as it may be some comparability issue of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by using `-Y` instead of `-X`.
So, the command would be:

```
ssh -Y user@host
$ glxgears
....
```

Some background information: When I was using Ubuntu (as the server and client - 18.04 days), using just `-X` worked fine for me. However, when I switched over to Arch, this stopped working. Some programs (like `lxterminal` and `xeyes`) do still work under Arch with just `-X`, but I found that programs like `glxgears` and `glxinfo` and others refuse to start with the error you described (`Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual`). After some searching, the Arch Wiki made the following note:

> Tip: You can enable the ForwardX11Trusted option (-Y switch on the command line) if GUI is drawing badly or you receive errors; this will prevent X11 forwardings from being subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls. Be sure you have read the warning at the beginning of this section if you do so.

Arch wiki link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenSSH#X11_forwarding.

I tried this and it worked for me. Looking into the security issues (I am not an expert on this), it seems that the main concern is that `-Y` allows for windows to take focus, grab input (for the keyboard and mouse), and inject input events. I figure that if you trust both machines (server and client) and the program(s) you are running over ssh X11 forwarding, then it should be fine. But, I am not an expert on this. More info can be found here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/security-concerns-with-x11-forwarding